# Performance of JSON vs metadata table

Tags: database-design, postgresql-9.4

I'm working on a system that contains readings from different sensors, some of which may contain more keys than a single reading. Due to them all being sensor readings, I am looking at having a single table to house these readings, with a field for the primary reading, but any extra information still needs to be stored.

For these extra bits of information, I am thinking of one of two solutions, however I'd like to know if anyone has done anything similar and has an idea of the difference in performance between the two.

**Option 1**

Store the extra data in a JSONB column within the sensor reading record itself. I've read that the JSONB implementation added in Postgres 9.4 is performant which is great, but I have no idea just how fast this would be for my use case (not really sure on the number of records I'm going to be handling just yet so hard to gauge.)

**Option 2**

Create a secondary "metadata" table effectively key-value store. One column representing the key, and the other representing the value. This would allow me to use proper indexing, and Postgres would be able to produce more accurate query plans.

Does anyone know which of this is likely to perform better? I am likely to be doing more insertions of records than reads, and when I do the reads, it is likely to be of many of the records at once, not just a single record which can influence this decision.

I would have thought going with **option 2** would likely be the better choice given that it isn't really unstructured data, and having the ability to index it would be beneficial, but if someone could confirm/reject this that would be great.

Comment: In your case I'd always prefer a key-value structure but can't confirm it fact-based so just take this as a confirmation to your gut feeling.

Comment: That was my thought, although since finding the name (EAV) I'm reading a lot of posts saying that it's a terrible thing to do and that I should just add multiple columns even if they're not used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used both, and it depends on how you want to query for the data. Generally PostgreSQL does quite well with joins.

Instead of going for Option 2 I would go completely normalized, ie define a table SensorReading, with key, value, a reference to the sensor table, and a timestamp. Indexes on timestamp and sensor_id. That's how I did it and it works well.

I have used option 1 for really big tables, for example tags in blog posts. In that case you can define a JSONB field or an array. It is not true it will perform bad, you can define a GIN array on those fields (btree would be pretty useless). So both options can be indexed.

So I would start completely normalized and then denormalize if needed in the future. For sure not Option 2 as you propose it.

Comment: how is a single table that contains a key and value pair different to a related table that contains the same key value pair?

Comment: You were mentioning to keep the first key-value pair in the main table, and put additional key-value pairs in a seperate table. The point I was trying to make was to not do that, and rather keep all key-value pairs in the same table.